# Elastic Search: applying changes of analyzers/tokenizers/filters settings to existing indices

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm quite new to ElasticSearch, so please forgive me if I overlook something obvious/basic.

I'd like to change the settings of analyzers/tokenizers/filters, and then apply them to existing indices. The only way I can come up with is the following:

1. create a new index.

   - Suppose you want to change the setting of `posts` index, create `posts-copy` index.
2. reindex `posts` to `posts-copy`.
3. delete `posts`.
4. re-create `posts` index, applying the new settings.
5. re-reindex `posts-copy` to `posts`.
6. delete `posts-copy`.

I tried this way using Ruby client of ElasticSearch, and it looked like it worked. However, I'm not sure if this approach really is proper. And I feel like it's quite redundant and there might be more efficient way of applying new settings.

I would appreciate it if you shed some lights on this problem.

Comment: Ruby code is really not required in this question :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what type of changes are you doing on `analyzers/tokenizers/filters`, if you are changing it on existing fields than these are breaking changes and you have to recreate the indices with new settings(like you mentioned), but if you are adding a new fields in the index and for that you are creating new settings, than you don't have to recreate the index, its called incremental changes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now it's crystal clear for me--I need not to reindex for incremental changes, but I need to if it's for existing fields.

Comment: @NullableYogurt glad it helped you clear the concept ::)